How to get the next page of API results using JSON in Python
I am trying to pull the next page of results from this link.
There are 503 total results, so I need results 501-503.
I am pulling the first page using this:
import json
import requests
api_url = 'https://investor.vanguard.com/investment-products/mutual-funds/profile/api/VFIAX/portfolio-holding/stock.json'
get_server_information = requests.get(api_url)
json_data = get_server_information.json()
pretty_data=json.dumps(json_data,indent=4)

I am trying to pull the next set using the links that have start=501&count=500, but no luck. I tried also using page=0, page=1, no luck. When I use start=501 or next or next_page, it is still pulling the first 500.
Here is what does not work:
import json
import requests
api_url = 'https://investor.vanguard.com/investment-products/mutual-funds/profile/api/VFIAX/portfolio-holding/stock&start=501'
get_server_information = requests.get(api_url)
json_data = get_server_information.json()
pretty_data=json.dumps(json_data,indent=4)


When I use start=501 or next or next_page show the code for when you do that, not the code that works.

@KamilCuk please see edits to the question for not working code

https://investor.vanguard.com/investment-products/mutual-funds/profile/api/VFIAX/portfolio-holding/stock.json?start=501&count=500 seems to work just fine (that is, use the investor.vanguard.com link you started with, rather than api.vanguard.com).
